# Calling os.Lstat only if the file has changed since the last time I called os.Lstat

Tags: go, system-calls

I'm trying to write a program, `calcsize`, that calculates the size of all sub directories. I want to create a cache of the result and only re-walk the directory if it has changed since the last time I've run the program.

Something like:

```
./calcsize
//outputs 
/absolute/file/path1/ 1000 Bytes
/absolute/file/path2/ 2000 Bytes
```

I'm already walking the dirs with my own walk implementation because the built in go `filepath.Walk` is already calling `Lstat` on every file.

Is there any way to know if a directory or set of files has changed without calling `Lstat` on every file? Maybe a system call I'm not aware of?

Comment: https://github.com/loov/watchrun/blob/master/watch/monitor.go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no. However you might want to look at: https://github.com/mattn/go-zglob/blob/master/fastwalk/fastwalk_unix.go

And using that data you can skip some of the stat calls, if you only care about files.

Comment: Definitely the right answer… I'll amend my question with some optimizations I found while doing some research on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Whether, and how, this is possible depends heavily on your operating system.  But you might take a look at [github.com/howeyc/fsnotify](https://github.com/howeyc/fsnotify) which claims to offer this (I've never used it--I just now found it via Google).

In general, look at any Go program that provides a 'watch' feature.  [GoConvey](http://goconvey.co/) and [GopherJS's serve mode](https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs) come to mind as examples, but there are others (possibly even in the standard library).

Comment: It seems like there might be quite a few problems with this approach after reading the [faq](https://github.com/howeyc/fsnotify#faq).